# Javascript function scope issues when passing function as parameter

Tags: javascript, class, scope

If I have the following:

```
var ScatterQuadrant = function ScatterQuadrant( id, _width, _height, methods )
{
    this.id = id;
    this.canvas = document.getElementById( id );
    this.canvas.width = _width;
    this.canvas.height = _height;   
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext( "2d" );
    methods();

}

function Init()
{
    var scatterQuad = new ScatterQuadrant( 
        "Frame", 800, 600, function()
        {      
            this.ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"; // this.ctx isn't going to work, but what will?
            this.ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, 150, 75 ); 
        }
    );

}
```

You will notice I have pushed in a function to my ScatterQuadrant function and I now want to access the parameter ctx in the calling function. How would I go about doing this (see my comment in the code)

Answer (score 2):

Calling a method *just like that*, will always reference `this` to the *global object* or `undefined` (ES5 strict mode).

You need to explicitly set the context, using `Function.prototype.call` for instance:

```
methods.call( this );
```

Comment: Thanks. working now! Ill mark as correct answer when it allows me to

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [MDN's introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (it rather should be called "context", "scope" is a different thing). In your case, using [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) will be enough:

```
methods.call(this);
```